# Notepad++ : Insert blank new line after match of some string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to insert new line after `(4)` option in whole document in notepad++

> 1. For his alleged involvement in
>      espio-nage
>      (1) abc
>      (2) sdf
>      (3) asf
>      (4) agg
> 2. When the Principal was entering
>      the class, all my friends quietly...
>      (1) dfg
>      (2) hsc
>      (3) sdg
>      (4) fse

Below expression is not working.
Find what: `^.+(4)`
Replace with: `\n$0`

Comment: Fyi `^\(4\).+` replace to `$0\n` would probably have worked.

Answer (score 4):

Should be like this.

Find: `(\(4\).+)`

Replace: `$1\n`

Keep in mind that the brackets `(` and `)` have a special meaning in regex, so you should escape them with `\`.

Comment: @Dani Come on, I just tried it myself, and it works just perfectly! :) Have you switched the search mode to Regular expression?

Comment: My mistake , Option "matches newline" was checked.
Thanks a ton mate , i have been trying since an hour

Comment: @Dani Cool, glad it works. Pls, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @Dani It's better to open a new question.